# How to update abp db table names to MySql convention like "abp_user_role"

Tags: mysql, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to convert the ABP template project's DB table names to MySql convention like 'abp_user_role', but failed for AbpRoleBase, AbpTenantBase, AbpUserBase, others are all good.

Following are my code in DB Context:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        UpdateAbpTableNamesForMySqlConvention(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TestEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id });

            entity.ToTable("test_entity");
        });

    }

    private void UpdateAbpTableNamesForMySqlConvention(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_audit_log"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<BackgroundJobInfo>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_background_job"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Edition>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_edition"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityChange>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_entity_change"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityChangeSet>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_entity_change_set"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityPropertyChange>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_entity_property_change"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<FeatureSetting>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_feature"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationLanguage>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_language"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationLanguageText>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_language_text"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<NotificationInfo>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_notification"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<NotificationSubscriptionInfo>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_notification_subscription"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationUnit>(e => e.ToTable("abp_organization_unit"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionSetting>(e => e.ToTable("abp_permission_setting"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleClaim>(e => e.ToTable("abp_role_claim"));
        //modelBuilder.Entity<AbpRoleBase>(e => e.ToTable("abp_role"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>(e => e.ToTable("abp_setting"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<TenantNotificationInfo>(e => e.ToTable("abp_tenant_notification"));
        //modelBuilder.Entity<AbpTenantBase>(e => e.ToTable("abp_tenant"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_account"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_claim"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLoginAttempt>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_login_attempt"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_login"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserNotificationInfo>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_notification"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserOrganizationUnit>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_organization_unit"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_role"));
        //modelBuilder.Entity<AbpUserBase>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserToken>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_token"));
```

}

**Got Error:**
The filter expression 'e => (Not(Convert(e, ISoftDelete).IsDeleted) OrElse (Convert(e, ISoftDelete).IsDeleted != value(Test.EntityFrameworkCore.TestDbContext).IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled))' cannot be specified for entity type 'Tenant'. A filter may only be applied to the root entity type in a hierarchy.

Comment: Configure `Tenant` instead of `AbpTenantBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct one:

```
   private void UpdateAbpTableNamesForMySqlConvention(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_audit_log"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<BackgroundJobInfo>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_background_job"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Edition>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_edition"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityChange>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_entity_change"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityChangeSet>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_entity_change_set"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityPropertyChange>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_entity_property_change"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<FeatureSetting>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_feature"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationLanguage>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_language"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationLanguageText>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_language_text"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<NotificationInfo>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_notification"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<NotificationSubscriptionInfo>(e => { e.ToTable("abp_notification_subscription"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationUnit>(e => e.ToTable("abp_organization_unit"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionSetting>(e => e.ToTable("abp_permission_setting"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleClaim>(e => e.ToTable("abp_role_claim"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(e => e.ToTable("abp_role"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>(e => e.ToTable("abp_setting"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<TenantNotificationInfo>(e => e.ToTable("abp_tenant_notification"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>(e => e.ToTable("abp_tenant"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_account"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_claim"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLoginAttempt>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_login_attempt"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_login"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserNotificationInfo>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_notification"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserOrganizationUnit>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_organization_unit"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_role"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserToken>(e => e.ToTable("abp_user_token"));
    }
```